# Memory Addressing

Tags: memory, addressing

How many bits would you need to address a **4M X 8** memory if

1. the memory is byte-addressable?
2. the memory is word-addressable with a word size of 16 bits?
3. the memory is word-addressable with a word size of 32 bits?

For #1, I have understood the solution as 4M = 2<sup>2</sup> x 2<sup>20</sup> = 2<sup>22</sup> = **22 bits**.

For #2 and #3, the answers provided in our lecture was:

- 4M X 8 bit memory requires **21 bit addresses** if it is word-addressable and word size is **16 bits**.
- 4M X 8 bit memory requires **20 bit addresses** if it is word-addressable and word size is **32 bits**.

**Question:**
How did it arrive to 21 and 20 bit addresses for 16-bit and 32-bit word sizes respectively?

**EDIT:**
**Homework:**
How many bits would you need to address a **2M X 32** memory if

1. the memory is byte-addressable?
2. the memory is word-addressable with a word size of 32 bits?

**Solutions:**

1. 2M = 2 x 2<sup>20</sup> = 2<sup>1</sup> x 2<sup>20</sup> = 2<sup>21</sup> = **21 bits**
2. 21 - [log 2 (32/32)] = 21 - [log 2 (1)] = 21 - 0 = **21 bits**

*Are my solutions correct?*

Comment: A lot of this might also depend on the addressing scheme you want to use. If you want full linear addressing, then the calculations are easy, however some architectures uses a segment (page) + offset type addressing scheme specifically to minimise the address size.

Comment: For the above given lecture example, what may be the mathematical solutions for #2 and #3? Do I simply subtract 1 or 2 from the byte-addressable bits (22 bits)?

Comment: No, you subtract log2(word_width/8) from the byte-addressible bits.

Comment: Just to confirm, is it **/8** because it is 4M X **8**?

Comment: Yes. (Unwritten in the question is how you reorganise a X8 memory to get 16 or 32 bits out of it, but that's another story.)

Comment: I have edited my post to include my actual homework problem. Based on the example and explanation given here, I have posted my solution. Can you kindly check if it is correct? Thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: Do your solutions make sense to you? If not, what seems odd about them?

Comment: Hi Brian, I find it odd that the word-addressable bit size (#2), is also the same as the byte-addressable bit size. Is a case like that possible?

Comment: remember you have to address an individual byte in one of these cases...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solutions to Homework:

1. 2M x 32
   = 2<sup>1</sup> x 2<sup>20</sup> x (2<sup>5</sup> / 2<sup>3</sup>)
   = 2<sup>1</sup> x 2<sup>20</sup> x 2<sup>2</sup>
   = 2<sup>23</sup>
   Answer: 23 bits for byte-addressable
2. 2M = 2<sup>1</sup> x 2<sup>20</sup> = 2<sup>21</sup>
   Answer: 21 bits for word-addressable

Comment: So, how do you select the highest order byte or address 0, and after that the lowest order byte of address 1?

Comment: Please note that this answer was provided by the OP and is the desired answer. @radagast If you would like to ask a different question please do not add it as a comment, as the issue of byte addressability within a multi-byte word is not part of the original question.

Comment: @JoeHass: I hadn't noticed that the answer was from OP himself, thanks for drawing my attention to it. About the question: it's rethorical. I know the answer.

Comment: Do we get neg-voted for answering your own question? I thought the StackExchange websites allowed "Q&A" posts if possible.

Comment: I don't think you got downvoted for answering your own question, but because people think it's the wrong answer. Actually so do I. Did you read my first comment here?

Comment: It is the correct answer (for the homework question) as also confirmed by the Instructor's Manual.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your solutions for the homework are correct. Note that for the 4Mx32 you only use 8 bits per 32 bit word. If you want to use all bits you'd need a 32-to-8 multiplexer/demultiplexer.

#2 and #3 of the lecture are a bit confusing. If the memory is word-addressable with 16-bit words, it's no longer a 4Mx8 memory but a 2Mx16 memory. To address 2M words you need 21 bits. Similar for #3.

Comment: I have been thinking something might have been wrong with the lecture example.